# Overriding words in the default Spell-Check dictionary

Tags: wpf, textbox, customization, spell-checking, dictionary

I've been playing with the Spell-Check capabilities in WPF 4.0 TextBox controls, including Custom Dictionaries, and while they are great; I was wondering if there was any way to **override** a word in the default dictionary.  Or, rather, override the default casing of a word.

Here's my example.  I work in the Property/Casualty insurance industry, and we have specific jargon that we use, just like any other industry.  For example, in dealing with auto accident claims, we use "IV" to refer to the Insured's Vehicle and "OV" to the Other Vehicle.  I am able to add "OV" to a custom dictionary and have the built-in spell-checking features trigger so that it should be typed in all upper case (for easier readability, among other things), but am unable to do so for IV, since it already seems to be in the default dictionary as "iv".  I have "IV" in my custom dictionary, but spell check does not flag an occurrence of "iv" as being incorrect.

I would like to be able to override the casing on that word so that it triggers when the user types "iv" instead of "IV".  Does anybody know of a way to do that?